# Callback function inside for loop - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop, callback

Hope you're having a good day. I recently discovered that it is not as easy to handle callbacks inside a `for` loop. I have tried a few things but couldn't find a solution.
Here is the code:

```
var book = new Array;
var chapters = Object.keys(epub.spine.contents).length;

for (let i = 0; i < chapters; i++) {
    let cacheArray = [];
    epub.getChapter(epub.spine.contents[i].id, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        //remove html tags
        let str = data.replace(/<\/?[\w\s]*>|<.+[\W]>/g, '');
        book.push(str)
    })
}
console.log(book)//returns empty array ofc
```

After this code is executed, I need to loop over the array to search its contents. If that was not the case, my approach would be to just send it to a db.

My approach was the following:

```
var recursiveChapter = function (n) {
    var book = new Array;
    if (n < chapters) {
        // chapter function
        epub.getChapter(epub.spine.contents[n].id, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
            }
            //remove HTML tags
            let str = data.replace(/<\/?[\w\s]*>|<.+[\W]>/g, '');
            book.push(str)
            recursiveChapter(n + 1)
        });
    }
}
//start the recursive function
recursiveChapter(0)
console.log(book)//returns an empty array
```

I am stuck and can't think of a way of using this data without storing it in a db.
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: can u tell us what did you expect this code do and what are you currently facing?

Comment: Why not promisify your `getChapter` function. It would be easier to await this method

Comment: @AliHussam getChapter comes from an external library, so yeah i can modify it but it's going to take me some time i think. (https://github.com/julien-c/epub) this library btw.

Comment: @arminyahya this fuctions basically parse an epub to a string, once it does that i can interact with it via an event emmiter. Once im there i need to load every chapter and remove html tags, push each chapter into an Array, and then i want to do a search with a forEach loop. The problem im having is that getChapter returns a callback, so the for loop just keep going and  if i try to use the Array it's allways empty, so i can't continue with the process i just mentioned.

Comment: Your function has an error first callback, you can simply do `util.promisify` to promisify it or write a promisifed wrapper for this call.

Comment: I'm not too familiarized with promises yet, i'm gonna give it a try, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can tackle this. One way is to use the [async library](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/), this allows to to run async. calls in parallel, or in series.

For example, we can use [async.mapSeries()](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#mapSeries) to get the result of a series of asynchronous calls as an array.

You input your array of ids, then the callback will return an array of the data returned, for example, I've mocked out the getChapter() function to give you an idea of how it would work:

```js
// Mock out epub object
const epub = { 
    getChapter(id, callback) {
        setTimeout(() => callback(null, "Data for id " + id), 250);
    }
}

let ids = [1,2,3,4];
console.log("Calling async.mapSeries for ids:", ids);
async.mapSeries(ids, epub.getChapter, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Result:", result)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.0/async.min.js" integrity="sha512-6K6+H87tLdCWvY5ml9ZQXLRlPlDEt8uXmtELhuJRgFyEDv6JvndWHg3jadJuBVGPEhhA2AAt+ROMC2V7EvTIWw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You could also promisify the epub call and use Promise.all to get the result, like so:

```js
epub = { 
    getChapter(id, callback) {
        setTimeout(() => callback(null, "Data for id " + id), 250);
    }
}
 
let ids = [1,2,3,4];

function getChapterPromisified(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        epub.getChapter(id, (err, data) => { 
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
    })
}

// Create a list of promises, one for each call
const promises = ids.map(id => getChapterPromisified(id))
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(result => console.log("Result:", result))
    .catch(error => console.error("An error occurred:", err));
```

Comment: Thx for the response Terry, the function im using comes from an external library (this one to be exact https://github.com/julien-c/epub), so i don't think i can modify it. I mean, sure i can, but it would probably take me some time since i really don't know how it was made(this one https://github.com/julien-c/epub). Your first answer tho, that might work, since i have a way of obtaining the id's. I'm gonna give it a try, thx a lot.

Comment: Thanks for testing my answer! You shouldn't have to modify the function,  maybe just add a wrapper if you want to go the promise route.  If you use the async approach,  you shouldn't have to modify the function at all!

Comment: Oh right, i could wrap it and return a promise, i didn't think of that. You see, i'm what people refers as a "noob" so i've never actually tryed that, but it looks interesting, i'm gonna check it out. Thx a lot.

Comment: Oh great, give those approaches a go. Just test them out and see if either suits you!

Comment: second one worked just fine, i had some issues just because i forgot to actually return the promise, wich gave me insanity for a few hours. Thx you!

Comment: Great, thanks for testing it! Promises are awkward to start with, but very useful once you're comfortable with them!